# Derivative of integral / Integral of derivative, but cannot use integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

[Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1iYy.jpg)

I don't know how to do either one of these integrals because I cannot use integration by parts. So there does not seem to be a way to integrate the product of the functions.

For part (b), I can expand the derivative and end up getting $\int^{\ln(\pi)}_{0} [2x e^x \sin(e^x)+2 \cos(e^x)]\,\mathrm dx$.

But then it becomes the same issue as part (a): cannot integrate further because of product of functions.

Comment: Can you use the fundamental theorem of calculus? There would be no need of expanding the derivative and those become quite trivial, you only need to know that those functions under the integral are indeed continuous

Comment: @SamueleMonitto Yes I am in Calc 1, can use Fundamental theorem of Calculus for sure. But for part (a), it's $d/dx$ but the integral is in variable $t$, so how would I even apply that?

Comment: Part (a) I would guess is just the derivative of a constant.

Comment: Umm I can't use Fundamental theorem (applying bounds) without the indefinite integral right? How can I show that it's a constant then?

Comment: It's constant with respect to x, because its value doesn't depend on x, the integral is just a number, hence the derivative with respect to x of something which doesn't depend on x is 0, you wouldn't need the fundamental theorem in this case.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it thanks. Any clue about approach for part (b)?

Comment: I will expand this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$\int_a^b \frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f(b)-f(a)$ , provided that $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))$ is continuous. In your case, your function is a product of infinitely many times differentiable functions, so you can apply the theorem and deduce the value of the integral by substituting the endpoints into the function.